# Asp.net web forms performance

Tags: asp.net, performance

what are the measures which reflects a highly scalable and with high performance asp.net form.

like time in seconds to load the page?

time in seconds to do data actions like Add delete.

page size.

Comment: Less is better. Use some tools like Chrome's Page Speed or Yahoo's YSlow to measure and get suggestions on where to make improvements.

Comment: In short there are so much other things that will matter that is not related to asp.net. Bandwidth, Server CPU(s), RAM and so on.. Then what ever asp.net is slower than php etc is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very open ended question. Performance and scalability can mean a whole host of different things. Serving a page quickly, or having it render in the browser quickly, is just one aspect of this. Tools such as Fiddler, YSlow etc can help you look at the time it takes a page, and all its assets (images, scripts etc) to get to the browser and become useful to the user, but this won't tell you whether your site can serve 10s, 100, 1000s or millions of users.

To determine the scalability of your site you need to start looking at profiling tools, such as those that ship in VS.NET. You'll be looking at numbers such as requests per second, CPU load, disk saturation. Generally, you'll want to understand what your scale unit is - how many users each of your servers can support at some given load (e.g. 80% CPU) before you need to go buy another server.

Finally, your system isn't scalable if you can't add new servers, or add new resources to your existing server (e.g. memory disk), to see an improvement. You need to know that your architecture supports being scaled out or scaled up.

If I were you I'd...

1. Define what acceptable performance means for you (how long you want users to wait for a page, how long it should take to perform an action etc)
2. See if you're hitting those requirements in the browser by measuring using the tools mentioned (Fiddler, YSlow etc).
3. Put your system under load using tools such as VS.NET's perf tooling and see where you're spending time and CPU. Fix stuff as you see it.
4. Read stuff like this: http://highscalability.com/ and look at the strategies that other sites use to scale. Find ones that work for you and try them out.

**update** from your comments to other answers you appear to be concerned about HOW to you should time stuff.

To use Fiddler for performance measurements look at this: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Perf/

To use IE's developer tools for measuring perf look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478

To use the Chrome developer tools look here: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

However, I really like Fiddler. Not only will it allow you to see performance, it can record the HTTP requests and then generate VS.NET Web Tests. This allows you to create a set of performance tests based upon real user interactions. As you change your code you can re-test and look for perf improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into some simple but useful tips on the Web that are highly recommended a combination of all of these will give you different results.

Front End Pro Tips
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

ASP.NET Pro Tips
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx

ASP.NET White Paper
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/GetFile.aspx?Page=Building-High-Performance-Websites&File=Building%20High%20Performance%20Web%20Applications.pdf

There are a few books also.
[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential/dp/0596529309](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309)
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849690683

Answer (score 0):

Avoid session state.

Reduce view-state.

Employ caching wherever you can: page, assets, controls, data, etc.

And as Martin suggests, establish baseline acceptance so you know what 'too slow' means.

Comment: guys i am asking about value in numbers lets say 6 seconds to load a page or 5 .. not how to do that

Comment: And we're saying we cannot come up with numbers for you. Look at StackOverflow - pages appear sub-sub-second. While we have a maintenance report in our app that takes 30 seconds. Both are reasonable in thier context.

Comment: @SShebly, 6 seconds to load a page is WAY to long. Think under a second. But also it's about what your trying to load, as n8wrl states reporting is different.